# Apply style to a email in YII2 (Gmail do not let me)

Tags: php, email, yii2

good afternoons! How can I make for add a style to this mail? I use YII2 with the swiftmailer library. Here is my example:

```
$a = Yii::$app -> mailer -> compose()
-> setFrom('')
-> setTo('')
-> setSubject('My title')
-> setTextBody('Plain text content')
-> setHtmlBody('My text')
-> send();
```

**mail/layout/html.php**

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;

/* @var $this \yii\web\View view component instance */
/* @var $message \yii\mail\MessageInterface the message being composed */
/* @var $content string main view render result */
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>" />
    <style type="text/css">
    .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border-color:#ccc;}
    .tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#ccc;color:#333;background-color:#fff;border-top-width:1px;border-bottom-width:1px;}
    .tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#ccc;color:#333;background-color:#f0f0f0;border-top-width:1px;border-bottom-width:1px;}
    .tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
    .tg .tg-b7b8{background-color:#f9f9f9;vertical-align:top}
    </style>
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php $this->beginBody() ?>
    <?= $content ?>
    <?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

Greethings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gmail and other web-based clients do strip out external stylesheets and/or head tags. (see https://litmus.com/blog/understanding-gmail-and-css-part-1)

Your best bet would be to inline all styles directly into the HTML elements

Answer (score 0):

In your project scaffolding you should have  a  mail directory with

mail/layout/html.php

inside this content

```
  <?php
  use yii\helpers\Html;

  /* @var $this \yii\web\View view component instance */
  /* @var $message \yii\mail\MessageInterface the message being composed */
  /* @var $content string main view render result */
  ?>
  <?php $this->beginPage() ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>" />
      <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
      <?php $this->head() ?>
  </head>
  <body>
      <?php $this->beginBody() ?>
      <?= $content ?>
      <?php $this->endBody() ?>
  </body>
  </html>
  <?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

i suggest you of format  and style in this area